# i'm working on an NFT collection following a tutorial video on web3 dao. my contract isnt compiling and it's showing the error below

Tags: solidity, web3js, nft

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "./IWhitelist.sol";

contract CryptoDevs is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    string _baseTokenURI;

    IWhitelist whitelist;
    bool public presaleStarted;
    uint256 public presaleEnded;
    uint256 public maxTokenIds = 20;
    uint256 public tokenIds;
    uint256 public _price = 0.01 ether;
    bool public _paused;

    modifier onlyWhenNotPaused() {
        require(!_paused, "contract currently paused");
        _;
    }

    constructor(string memory baseURI, address whitelistContract)
        ERC721("Crypto Devs", "CD")
    {
        _baseTokenURI = baseURI;
        whitelist = IWhitelist(whitelistContract);
    }

    function startPresale() public onlyOwner {
        presaleStarted = true;
        presaleEnded = block.timestamp + 5 minutes;
    }

    function presaleMint() public payable onlyWhenNotPaused {
        require(
            presaleStarted && block.timestamp < presaleEnded,
            "Presale ended"
        );
        require(
            whitelist.whitelistedAddress(msg.sender),
            "you're not in whitelist"
        );

        require(tokenIds < maxTokenIds, "Exceeded the limit");
        require(msg.value >= _price, "Ether sent is not correct");

        tokenIds += 1;

        _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenIds);
    }

    function mint() public payable onlyWhenNotPaused {
        require(
            presaleStarted && block.timestamp >= presaleEnded,
            "Presale has not ended yet"
        );
        require(tokenIds < maxTokenIds, "Exceeded the limit");
        require(msg.value >= _price, "Ether sent is not correct");
        tokenIds += 1;

        _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenIds);
    }

    function _baseURI() internal view override returns (string memory) {
        return _baseTokenURI;
    }

    function setPaused(bool val) public onlyOwner {
        _paused = val;
    }

    function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
        address _owner = owner();
        uint256 amount = address(this).balance;
        (bool sent, ) = _owner.call{value: amount}("");
        require(sent, "failed to send ether");
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    fallback() external payable {}
}
```

The error

```
TypeError: Member "whitelistedAddress" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract IWhitelist.
  --> contracts/CryptoDevs.sol:43:13:
   |
43 |             whitelist.whitelistedAddress(msg.sender),
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

Comment: //SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

interface IWhitelist {
    function whitelistedAddresses(address) external view returns (bool);
}                                                                                                                                                                                                      //this is the contract on IWhitelist.sol

Comment: There is a difference: `whitelistedAddress` vs `whitelistedAddresses`.